# Modifying method in java is not working

Tags: java, class, methods

**Class**

```
public JTime add(JTime t2){
    JTime sum = new JTime();
    sum.hour = this.hour + t2.hour;
    sum.minute = this.minute + t2.minute;
    sum.second = this.second + t2.second;
    return sum;
}

public void increment (double seconds){
    this.second = seconds;
    while(this.second >= 60.0){
        this.second -= 60.0;
        this.minute += 1;
    }
    while(this.minute >= 60.){
        this.minute -=60;
        this.hour +=1;
    }
    while(this.hour >= 24){
        int result = this.hour - 24;
        this.hour = result;
    }


}
```

**Main**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JTime startTime = new JTime(22, 50, 0.0);
    JTime runningTime = new JTime(5, 16, 0.0);
    JTime endTime = startTime.add(runningTime);
    System.out.println(endTime);
    }
}
```

I am simply following a method published in a book. What I am trying to achieve here is to display time in 24 hour format. The `increment` method should be doing that, but it is not.

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you actually invoke `increment`.

Comment: The book I am reading doesn't mention anything about invoking so I assumed that the method will change it automatically.

Comment: What is your expected input and output, and what is your real output?

Comment: I can't speak to the book, but no, methods don't get automatically/magically invoked in Java.

Comment: http://greenteapress.com/thinkjava6/html/thinkjava6012.html#sec138

If you look at 11.9, this is what it says.

Comment: No, the explanation in the article only says that your original object will not be mordified but a new one with the changed values returned, not that the method will get magically called. @yshavit is right, methods must be invoked to do *anything*.

Answer (score 0):

The add method returns an object so you need to override its toString or create a method that returns the individual resulting values. For example:

```
 @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        return "Hours:"+this.hour+", minutes:"+this.minute+", seconds:"+this.second;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using integer division `/` (7/5==1) and modulo `%` (7%5==2) one can
repair overflows in the three fields:

```
int hour;
int minute;
int second;

public JTime plus(JTime t2) {
    JTime sum = new JTime();
    sum.hour = this.hour + t2.hour;
    sum.minute = this.minute + t2.minute;
    sum.second = this.second + t2.second;
    normalize();
    return sum;
}

private void normalize() {
    minute += second / 60;
    second %= 60;
    hour += minute / 60;
    minute %= 60;
    hour %= 24;
}

public void increment(int seconds) {
    second += seconds;
    normalize();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
}
```

Renaming `add` as `plus` to indicate that the time object itself is not incremented, but a new time is delivered.

For addition an overflow (number of days) would be nice.